# Why using A PCB is better than used a bread board or a vero board?

Tags: pcb

Why using A PCB is better than used a bread board or a vero board? i want some advantage of this

Comment: Who says a PCB is better? If you only ever want to make one off and you aren't sure exactly which components to use, a prototype board is better.

Comment: I  HAVE AN ESSAY AND NEED TO SAY WHY USING A PCB IS BETTER THAN OHTER BOARD.

Comment: Then do your own research - and don't SHOUT!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework question with no effort shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all they are used in different situations.

Often a PCB is a pretty definitive design, breadboard and vero board is mostly used for experimenting with certain (simple) circuits or testing certain principles.

With breadboards and vero boards you can have a lot of unwanted parasitic capacitance. Depending on your application this can have a lot of unwanted consequences for example erratic behavior in high speed applications. In most applications breadboard and vero board work fine.

Another disadvantage is that a breadboard or veroboard allows you less flexibility in routing a component or group of components in the recommended way. It can sometimes be a pain to make a circuit in the recommended way(analog and digital separated, high speed/low speed etc, all the normal design rules) on a breadboard or vero board. Last but not least, most components are fine pitch SMD components these days, the only way to use these on breadboard or vero board is to use an adapter board.

Comment: printed circuit features (eg: inverted F antenna)  are another thing you need pcb for.